# Remove all the numeric and alphanumeric characters from text file using

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have 2 text files:

File1 - Format of this file is `user_id   tweet_id    tweet_text`

**File 1**

```
60730027    6298443824  thank you echo park. you've changed A LOT, but as long as I'm getting paid to make you move, I'm still with it! 2009-12-03 02:54:10
60730027    6297282530  fat Albert Einstein goin in right now over here!!!  2009-12-03 01:35:22
```

**File2**
The format of this file is `genome_id   name   ascii_name`

```
4045417 Southwest Indent    Southwest Indent
4045418 Southeast Point     Southeast Point
```

Below is the code snippet to read file 1:

```
public void readfromFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner inputStream;
    String source=null;
     FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("file1.txt");   
        String regex = "/[a-zA-Z ]+/";
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file); 

        while(fileScan.hasNextLine()){
            word = fileScan.nextLine();
            word = word.replaceAll(regex, "").toLowerCase();
            PrintWriter outputStreamName = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("temp.txt"));
            outputStreamName.printf("%s",word);
}
```

My intention here is firstly to replace data present in user_id,tweet_id,genome_id with null value. Then convert the uppercase values to lowercase. However, right now whenever this code processes file1, nothing changes to text file. I am also wondering what is happening. When I output this to the console, I get the output.

Expected output:

```
thank you echo park youve changed a lot but as long as im getting paid to make you move im still with it

fat albert einstein goin in right now over here
```

Comment: If you want to change the file you should WRITE on it, open the file using PrintWriter and write your data!

Comment: what about this `I'm` and `you've` that is changed to `Im` and `youve`? Is it accepted?

Comment: @user3218114 - My mistake. I have removed these values from the output.

Comment: @WajdyEssam - I have added below code inside the loop.  PrintWriter outputStreamName = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("temp.txt"));
outputStreamName.printf("%s",word);

Comment: No worries Look at my answer and let me know if you want something else.

Comment: what is your next edit? If you edit your original code then there is no meaning of any answers.

Comment: @user3218114 - Oh okie my apologies. I was not sure how to put in my new edited code. Site suggested to edit my post instead of answering my own question.

Comment: Just add it in the end of your question. So simple.

Comment: Does still problem persist? Are answers helpful?

Comment: @MattRyan Since you deleted your last question I'll answer here:  even if you're building a rocket to the moon and back - it's still a lame excuse for using 5 nested loops. Refactor your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Expected output, You want to replace everything other than letters, dot and spaces between words.

```
[^a-zA-Z. ]+|(?<=\d)\s*(?=\d)|(?<=\D)\s*(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s*(?=\D)
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV4fE6/1)

OR try without [**Lookaround**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
[^a-zA-Z. ]+|\d\s+\d|\D\s+\d|\d\s+\D
```

Here `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

sample code:

```
String regex = "[^a-zA-Z. ]+|(?<=\\d)\\s*(?=\\d)|(?<=\\D)\\s*(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)\\s*(?=\\D)";
str.replaceAll(regex,"");
```

output:

```
thank you echo park. youve changed A LOT but as long as Im getting paid to make you move Im still with it
fat Albert Einstein goin in right now over here
```

---

To exclude `'` as well from the output use `[^a-zA-Z.' ]+` otherwise `I'm` and `you've` are changed to `Im` and `youve`.

**Better** use `[a-zA-Z']+` to get all the words only. Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV4fE6/2)

Sample code:

```
String str = "60730027    6297282530  fat Albert Einstein goin in right now over here!!!  2009-12-03 01:35:22 ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z']+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.print(m.group()+" ");
}
```

output:

```
fat Albert Einstein goin in right now over here
```

---

**Note:** You are checking for next line hence

Change:

```
source = inputStream.next();
```

To:

```
source = inputStream.nextLine();
```

Comment: Yes I got what you mean to say. I have made some changes in the code, and edited my post. Could you please check? I want to change the upper case values to lower case and dump the value present in source to a text file.

Comment: just use `m.group().toLowerCase()` and write in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void readfromFile() throws Exception
{

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("file1.txt");    

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int ch;
    while((ch = file.read()) != -1){
        builder.append((char)ch);
    }

    System.out.println(builder.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s]", ""));

}
```

Scanner filter the empty string.

For ex

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("60730027    6298443824  thank");
while(scanner.hasNext())    //Read from file till the last line of the file.
{
    System.out.print(scanner.next());
}
```

**Output**

607300276298443824thank

So we cannot use scanner.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work either. The file is intact with no changes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s+", "").replaceAll(" +\\S+ \\S+$", "");
```